# Replace First and Last Word of String in the Most Pythonic Way

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am looking for the most pythonic way to replace the first and last word of a string (doing it on a letter basis won't work for various reasons).  To demonstrate what I'm trying to do, here is an example.

```
a = "this is the demonstration sentence."
```

I'd like the result of my python function to be:

```
b = "This is the demonstration Sentence."
```

The tricky part of it is that there might be spaces on the front or the end of the string.  I need those to be preserved.

Here's what I mean:

```
a = " this is a demonstration sentence. "
```

The result would need to be:

```
b = " This is a demonstration Sentence. "
```

Would also be interested in opinions on whether a regex would do this job better than python's inbuilt methods, or vice versa.

Comment: Why would you want/need to capitalize the last word of a sentence?

Comment: @martineau Maybe it's homework... but I'm only guessing :).

Comment: @martineau No reason - I'm looping through HTML doing bits and pieces.  capitalising is a proxy for what I'm actually doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import re
a = " this is a demonstration sentence. "
print(re.sub(r'''(?x)      # VERBOSE mode
             (             # 
              ^            # start of string
              \s*          # zero-or-more whitespaces 
              \w           # followed by an alphanumeric character
              )        
             |             # OR
             (
             \w            # an alphanumeric character
             \S*           # zero-or-more non-space characters
             \s*           # zero-or-more whitespaces
             $             # end of string
             )
             ''',
             lambda m: m.group().title(),
             a))
```

yields

```
 This is a demonstration Sentence.
```

Comment: huh.. what is wrong about `^\s*(\S)|(\w)\S*\s*$` that you have to use non-capturing groups?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you:

```
In [9]: a = "this is the demonstration sentence."

In [10]: left, _, right = a.strip().partition(' ')

In [11]: mid, _, right = right.rpartition(' ')

In [12]: Left = left.title()

In [13]: Right = right.title()

In [14]: a = a.replace(left, Left, 1).replace(right, Right, 1)

In [15]: a
Out[15]: 'This is the demonstration Sentence.'
```

Comment: What happens if you have `"This is the sentence sentence."`

Comment: In that case, do `a = a.replace(left, Left, 1); a=list(a); ind = a.rfind(right); a = list(a); a[ind:ind+len(right)] = Right; a=''.join(a)`

Comment: With a="  This is the sentence sentence.  " the answer code produces '  This is the demonstration sentence Sentence.  ' because right is 'sentence.'.  Also, the comment's code produces «AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'»

Comment: first time I've seen partition() and title()!

Comment: Sorry about the typo in my comment (from editing): `a = a.replace(left, Left, 1); find = a.rfind(right); a = list(a); a[ind:ind+len(right)] = right.replace(right.strip(), Right)+' '*(len(right)-len(right.strip()); a=''.join(a)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex solution:

```
def cap(m):
    return m.group(0).title()

re.sub(r'(?:^\s*\w+)|(?:[^\s]+\s*$)',cap," this is a demonstration sentence. ")
' This is a demonstration Sentence. '
```

Sorry, that's the best I can do ...

Regex breakdown:

```
(?:^\s*\w+)    #match (optional) whitespace and then 1 word at the beginning of the string
|              #regex "or"
(?:[^\s]+\s*$) #match a string of non-whitespace characters followed by (optional) whitespace and the end of the line.
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to inspectorG4dget, but using `.rsplit()` giving it the *maxsplit* argument, and `.capitalize()` instead.

Note: `.split()` also accepts an optional *maxsplit* argument, to split from the left.

```
>>> a = " this is a demonstration sentence. "
>>> part_one, part_two = a.rsplit(" ", 1)
>>> " ".join([part_one.capitalize(), part_two.capitalize()])
'This is the demonstration Sentence.'
```

`.rsplit()` splits the text from the right, where the *maxsplit* argument tells it how many splits to perform.  The value `1` will give you one "*split*" from the right.

```
>>> a.rsplit(" ", 1)
['this is the demonstration', 'sentence.']
```

Comment: This doesn't preserve the whitespace at the beginning and the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = " this is a demonstration sentence. "
sentence = sentence.split(' ')  # Split the string where a space occurs

for word in sentence:
    if word:  # If the list item is not whitespace
        sentence[sentence.index(word)] = word.title()
        break  # now that the first word's been replaced, we're done

# get the last word by traversing the sentence backwards
for word in sentence[::-1]:
    if word:
        sentence[sentence.index(word)] = word.title()
        break

final_sentence = ' '.join(sentence)
```